# How to ignore a sub package.json file when publishing to npm

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, publish, package.json

So I want to publish my package to npm. It is a cli that can create custom project for my company.

I have a subfolder containing the template of that project, and this includes a package.json file (which btw has a files property).

Now the problem is when I publish it on npm, when going threw the files in the project template, it doesn’t add the files because it follows the specific package.json instead of the root one.

So I would like npm publish to consider all files in my template, ignoring the files property inside that folder’s package.json

Thank you all :)